# Issue Setting new routes in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using express.js to create an app and have two ejs pages that can be navigated to but want to be able to navigate to more ejs (im using pug) pug so my app can be dynamic and i would like more of my links and hrefs to be able to use these routes.

```
This page works and uses ejs <pug):
// LOGIN PAGE
app.post('/', ifLoggedin, [
    body('user_email').custom((value) => {
        return dbConnection.execute('SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=?', [value])
            .then(([rows]) => {
                if (rows.length == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                return Promise.reject('Invalid Email Address!');
            });
    }),
    body('user_pass', 'Password is empty!').trim().not().isEmpty(),
], (req, res) => {
    const validation_result = validationResult(req);
    const { user_pass, user_email } = req.body;
    if (validation_result.isEmpty()) {

        dbConnection.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=?", [user_email])
            .then(([rows]) => {
                bcrypt.compare(user_pass, rows[0].password).then(compare_result => {
                    if (compare_result === true) {
                        req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
                        req.session.userID = rows[0].id;

                        res.redirect('/');
                    }
                    else {
                        res.render('login-register', {
                            login_errors: ['Invalid Password!']
                        });
                    }
                })
                    .catch(err => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });


            }).catch(err => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
    }
    else {
        let allErrors = validation_result.errors.map((error) => {
            return error.msg;
        });
        // REDERING login-register PAGE WITH LOGIN VALIDATION ERRORS
        res.render('login-register', {
            login_errors: allErrors
        });
    }
});
// END OF LOGIN PAGE
```

Ive attempted to create a route to here but it doesnt work nd the page returns a 404:
Here is the code thts breaking

```
// Testing >>>

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    //  render testicles
    res.sendFile('test.ejs');
});


// Testing ^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an absolute path directly with `res.sendFile`.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './view', 'test.ejs'))
```

or

```
res.sendFile('test.ejs', { root: path.join(__dirname, './views') });
```